# Join two rows in javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose we have two objects in memory:

```
const a = [{
  id: 123,
  width: 5
}, {
  id: 345,
  width: 10
}];

const b = [{
  id: 345,
  height: 2
}, {
  id: 123,
  height: 3
}];
```

Now we expect the join of the two objects (database join):

```
const c = join(a, b);
assert.true(c === {
  id: 123,
  width: 5,
  height: 3
}, {
  id: 345,
  width: 10,
  height: 2
});
```

Is there any handy "join" function? Or do us have to reivent the wheel?

Comment: `c === {
  id: 123,
  width: 5,
  height: 3
}, {
  id: 345,
  width: 10,
  height: 2
}` I think this would be always false  ...... also you are  missing `[....]`

Comment: Loop over `a` and for each entry look in `b` if there's an element with the same id. If so get the `height` and you have your own little (in time to implement and lines of code) `join` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `map` for same `id` and collect the properties in a new object.

```js
const
    a = [{ id: 123, width: 5 }, { id: 345, width: 10 }],
    b = [{ id: 123,  height: 3 }, { id: 345,  height: 2 }],
    c = [a, b].reduce((m => (r, a) => {
        a.forEach(o => {
            if (!m.has(o.id)) m.set(o.id, r[r.push({}) - 1]);
            Object.assign(m.get(o.id), o);
        });
        return r
    })(new Map), []);

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```